# Finish this class method - Do you know how?

Tags: java, class

Could someone help me out finishing this task? I'd be very grateful!

**Finish the class method 'copy(Fraction source, Fraction target)', so that after calling this method 'source' is unchanged and 'target' is made identical to 'source'.**

*At this line: target = source; // Here I need to put the code*

```html
class Fraction {

    Integer nominator;       
    Integer denominator;      

}

class Main
{
 public static void copy(Fraction source, Fraction target)
 {
  target = source; // Here I need to put the code
 }

 public static Fraction createFraction(Integer nominator, Integer denominator)
 {
        Fraction fraction = new Fraction();
        fraction.nominator = nominator;
        fraction.denominator = denominator;
        return fraction;
 }

 public static void main(String[] arguments)
 {
  final Integer ONE = 1;
  final Integer TWO = 2;
  final Integer THREE = 3;
  final Fraction SOURCE = createFraction(ONE, TWO);
  final Fraction TARGET = createFraction(TWO, THREE);
  copy(SOURCE, TARGET);
  System.out.println("SOURCE: " + toString(SOURCE));
  System.out.println("TARGET: " + toString(TARGET));
 }

 public static String toString(Fraction fraction)
 {
                return fraction.nominator + "/" + fraction.denominator;

 }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Hi Carcigenicate, I need the solution for this task.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for getting answers to assignments/homework. You should show us what solutions you have tried, what didn't work, or specifically what you do not understand about the code/question. If you show work and detail what you don't understand, then plenty of users will be happy to help you.

Comment: I didn't understand how to use the code. Nevertheless, I would like to thank Elliott Frisch for his detailed explanation. Now it is very clear!  And I'll take your feedback. I'll post everything I've already attempted the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Update `target` (not the reference), specifically copy the `source` `nominator` and `denominator` values to `target.nominator` and `target.denominator` respectively. Like,

```
public static void copy(Fraction source, Fraction target)
{
    // target = source; // Good try, but this just updates a local reference
    target.nominator = source.nominator; // <-- copy the `nominator`
    target.denominator = source.denominator; // <-- copy the `denominator`
}
```

Alternatively, but along the same lines, add a `setFraction` function to `Fraction` like,

```
public void setFraction(Fraction f) {
    this.nominator = f.nominator;
    this.denominator = f.denominator;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't modify `toString()` like that. Add it to `Fraction` as well,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return nominator + "/" + denominator;
}
```

And I would also override `Object.equals(Object)` in `Fraction`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o instanceof Fraction) {
        Fraction that = (Fraction) o;
        return nominator.equals(that.nominator) && denominator.equals(that.denominator);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can write

```
public static void copy(Fraction source, Fraction target)
{
    target.setFraction(source);
}
```

And if you followed along with `toString` then

```
System.out.println("SOURCE: " + toString(SOURCE));
System.out.println("TARGET: " + toString(TARGET));
```

Can be

```
System.out.println("SOURCE: " + SOURCE);
System.out.println("TARGET: " + TARGET);
System.out.println("TARGET.equals(SOURCE): " + TARGET.equals(SOURCE));
```